# How to Force UPDATE of MySQL Record When Nothing Is Changing

Tags: mysql, onupdate

My database table has a column defined to use `ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`:

- Field: last_access
- Type: timestamp
- Collation:
- Attributes: on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
- Null: No
- Default: CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
- Extra: ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

How can I force this `last_access` field to update for a given record when no other data in the record is changing?

Comment: Well if that's all you want to update maybe just set it? Or see if making it null would then update it to over write the null with the current time..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`UPDATE your_table SET last_access = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP();` ?

Comment: Honestly I've been tripping on this answer thinking something is missing in it.  Basically its good. So I needed something like this to convince me,

    UPDATE table SET col1 = 'value1', updated_at = now() where col2 = 'value2'

By updating a timestamp column updated_at which never fails to update the schema will know that something has definitely changed so it  "overwrites" other columns as well

Answer (score 0):

You have to also update a timestamp column in the process

```
UPDATE table SET col1 = 'value1', updated_at = now() where col2 = 'value2'
```