# Force MySQL to update TIMESTAMP column

Tags: mysql, timestamp, auto-update

I *believe* I have set my 5.6.17 ver MySQL server to recognize IANA TZ Databases as evidenced by

- a system_time_zone variable being set to "Pacific Daylight Time"
- a time_zone variable being set to UTC
- NOW(), giving me a standard SQL format date time

I thought that that would be sufficient to create an auto updating time stamp field, but, if I create a table via:

```
CREATE TABLE test (
  id SERIAL,
  stamp TIMESTAMP,
  stuff VARCHAR(255)
);
INSERT INTO test ( stuff ) VALUES ( 'abc' );
SELECT * FROM test;
```

records seem to be created with NULL in the stamp field:

```
id  stamp   stuff
1   NULL    abc
```

I thought that maybe the date gets entered only when doing an update, but when I update:

```
UPDATE test SET note = 'xyz' WHERE id = 1;
```

still the stamp is NULL

```
id  stamp   stuff
1   NULL    xyz
```

I attempted to change the create as

```
stamp TIMESTAMP DEFAULT NOW(),
```

which provides a proper value, but the stamp field remains unchanged when I update (even minutes later).

I also attempted to use

```
stamp TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
```

which, also, gave me an initial value, but never changed when updating.

Also, attempting to append AUTO_INCREMENT didn't seem to work for me.  Did I mention that I'm a MySQL newb?

How do I force my TIMESTAMP field to fill at creation and modify when updated?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/timestamp-initialization.html

basically `CREATE TABLE t1 (
  ts TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A field with type `TIMESTAMP` is also just another field without any special properties like auto initialization or update.

`DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` only sets the current timestamp when you *create the row*.

**You are looking for the property**  **`ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`**. This will set the timestamp *each time you update the row*, given that at least one of the row's values actually changes.

For more infos, have a look at the MySQL docs regarding [Automatic Initialization and Update for TIMESTAMP](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/timestamp-initialization.html).

Bottom line, create your table like this and `stamp` will always give you the timestamp of the last change:

```
CREATE TABLE test (
  id SERIAL,
  stamp TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  stuff VARCHAR(255)
);
```

Comment: Important note: `ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` will update ONLY if row's values REALLY changes. So, if you'll update  your row with same values then `ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` value is not changed. For force update the `ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` value use similar to - http://stackoverflow.com/a/9218768/987850

Comment: what if you want the timestamp to update even if no row changes value, but an update statement is executed?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry can't comment without enough reputation, and I don't know what is IANA TZ Database

But you can try to add `On update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` when you create the table:

```
CREATE TABLE test (
    id SERIAL,
    stamp TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,`
    stuff VARCHAR(255)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

it is quite simple

```
update table set fieldname=now() where fieldname = value;
```

here we assume that field we try to update is timestamp type field